# Firebase messaging send() errors with UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have the following code that seems to be erroring out sometimes, but I am not sure why I can't catch the error and am getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

```
(node:18) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:18) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:250:16)
    at validateMessage (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:359:15)
    at Messaging.send (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:500:9)
    at pushLike (/app/build/schema/swipe.js:407:41)
(node:18) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 9)
```

```
            if (!_.has(persona_2.profile, 'push_token')) {
                return;
            }

            const { rowCount: badge } = await Chat.knex().raw(newChatCountSql, {
                personaId: context.user.profile.persona[0].id,
            });

            admin.messaging().send({
                token: persona_2.profile.push_token,
                notification: {
                    title: 'my title',
                    body: 'hello world',
                },
                data: {},
                apns: {
                    payload: {
                        aps: {
                            badge,
                            sound: 'default',
                        },
                    },
                },
                // topic: chatId,
            })
                .catch(err => {
                    if (['messaging/invalid-registration-token', 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered'].includes(err.code)) {
                        // push token is no longer valid
                    } else {
                        log.error(err);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is `Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required`.

So sometimes `persona_2.profile.push_token` may be null.

Could you check `persona_2.profile` has `push_token` key and `persona_2.profile.push_token` is not null.

```
            if (!_.has(persona_2.profile, 'push_token') || !persona_2.profile.push_token) {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Oh wow, I expected `_.has(persona_2.profile, 'push_token')` to return `false` if `{ push_token: null }`, but it returns `true`. Didn't know `_.has()` was just a key check. Maybe I should instead just use `_.get()` or `_.result()` or `push_token != null`. Thanks, and probably explains a lot more bugs because I use it all over my code!